# Problem in parameter type inheritance from parent class method

Tags: typescript

Let's take a look at a simple example:

```
class Animal {
    eat(foodName: string) {
        console.log(`eating ${foodName}`);
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    private counter = 0;

    eat(foodName) { // here is the error "Parameter 'foodName' implicitly has an 'any' type."
        super.eat(foodName);
        this.counter++;
    }
}
```

Let's imagine a lot of inherited class methods. I do not want to duplicate their parameter types in this case. What can I do here?

I want to use something like this, but this is wrong:

```
eat(foodName: Parameters<super.eat>)
```

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what your goal is. Why not just `eat(foodName: string) { `? in Dog? Do you want it to be dynamic in some way?

Comment: Child classes can have broader input types than their parents, hence the default assumption of `any`. `eat(foodNameOrIndex: string | number): void` would be a valid implementation within `Dog`, for example.

Comment: You can have something like this `eat(foodName: Parameters<Animal["eat"]>[0]) {` or `eat(...[foodName]: Parameters<Animal["eat"]>)` but this looks super ugly IMO.

Comment: There's nothing you can do, really, other than to annotate them... and maybe go upvote [microsoft/TypeScript#23911](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23911) since that's the currently open feature request that would meet your needs, I think.  You could possibly write some functions to help with inference, but unless you have a truly gargantuan number of inherited methods I don't imagine the helper functions will be less clunky.  Does that fully address the question? If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?